# Groupby of multiple columns and assigning values to each by considering start and end of each (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, pandas-groupby

I've got a datframe that looks like that

```
df1
    v   w   x   y                               
4   0   1   a   b
5   0   1   a   a
_________________
6   0   2   a   b
_________________
2   0   3   a   b 
- - - - - - - - -   
3   1   2   a   b
_________________
15  1   3   a   b
12  1   3   b   b
_________________
13  1   1   a   b
- - - - - - - - - 
15  3   1   a   b
14  3   1   b   a
8   3   1   a   b
9   3   1   a   a
```

so df1 were grouped (lines) by v and w and merged with another df which contained x and y.
I need a new column z which picks the right group out of x and y with the following conditions:

1. in Every subgroup 'V'(dotted line) the first group should be of 'x' (x always starts with 'a' within groups, y always starts with 'b')
2. based on the end letter of each group (a or b) the next group should start with b (column'y') or a (column 'x')
3. if both groups end with the same letter, pick next group out of 'x'

Should Look like this:

```
df1
    v   w   x   y   z                            
4   0   1   a   b   a
5   0   1   a   a   a
_____________________
6   0   2   a   b   b
_____________________
2   0   3   a   b   a
- - - - - - - - - -- -   
3   1   2   a   b   a
_____________________
15  1   3   a   b   b
12  1   3   b   b   b
_____________________
13  1   1   a   b   a
 - - - - - - - - - - 
15  3   1   a   b   a
14  3   1   b   a   b
8   3   1   a   b   a
9   3   1   a   a   a
```

so basically last letter of a group and first letter of next group within subgroups of 'v' should be different.
Is that understandable and could anyone help me?

Comment: Anyone got an idea?

Comment: maybe assigning vaues 1-4 to each group                                                               
1=starts with a, ends with a, 2=starts with a, ends with b, 3=starts with b, ends with b, 4= starts with b, ends with a?

Answer (score 1):

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
s=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['x','y']],axis=1),index=df.index)[1].iloc[::-1].ne('b').cumsum()
df.groupby([df.v,df.w,s]).ngroup()
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     4
5     5
6     5
7     3
8     6
9     6
10    6
11    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: wait, how do i get column z out of this one?

Comment: @MirekG df['Z']=df.groupby([df.v,df.w,s]).ngroup()

Comment: yes, but s has only numbers since you did a cumsum. What exactly are you trying to do with the iloc ne() and cumsum() ? Sorry for asking and a big thanks.

Comment: @MirekG that is creat the sub_group

Comment: okay, what to do after that? how do I get the column z like in the example? with a,a,b,... Thank you in advance:)

Comment: know what I mean? Would be awesome:)

Comment: @MirekG try to understand the logic

Comment: the np.sort mixes columns x and y row by row, but I want the groups in x and y to stay as they are. Then you turn around the df, bool out the 'b' and count them up. But as I mentioned I want the whole group of x or y depending on the value in the group before.