# Column that counts up within subgroups pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I've got a df

```
df1
    a   b                                  
4   0   1      
5   0   1      
6   0   2      
2   0   3          
3   1   2   
15  1   3   
12  1   3   
13  1   1     
15  3   1   
14  3   1   
8   3   3   
9   3   2   
10  3   1
```

the df should be grouped by a and b and I need a column c that goes up from 1 to amount of groups within subgroups of a

```
df1
    a   b  c                                
4   0   1  1    
5   0   1  1    
6   0   2  2    
2   0   3  3        
3   1   2  1 
15  1   3  2 
12  1   3  2 
13  1   1  3   
15  3   1  1 
14  3   1  1 
8   3   3  2 
9   3   2  3 
10  3   1  4
```

How can I do that?

Comment: oh, fixed it. I need the second one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can do `groupby` + `transform` `factorize`

```
df['C']=df.groupby('a').b.transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]+1)
4     1
5     1
6     2
2     3
3     1
15    2
12    2
13    3
15    1
14    1
8     1
9     1
10    2
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you, works perfectly. Maybe you can have a look on this one, which is a bit more complex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521190/groupby-of-multiple-columns-and-assigning-values-to-each-by-considering-start-an . Would be awesome!:)

Answer (score 1):

Just so we can see the loop version

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

x = defaultdict(count)
y = {}
c = []

for a, b in zip(df.a, df.b):
    if (a, b) not in y:
        y[(a, b)] = next(x[a]) + 1
    c.append(y[(a, b)])

df.assign(C=c)

    a  b  C
4   0  1  1
5   0  1  1
6   0  2  2
2   0  3  3
3   1  2  1
15  1  3  2
12  1  3  2
13  1  1  3
15  3  1  1
14  3  1  1
8   3  3  2
9   3  2  3
10  3  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is groupby a and then iterate through each group and groupby b. Then use can use ngroup

```
df['c'] = np.hstack([g.groupby('b').ngroup().to_numpy() for _,g in df.groupby('a')])

    a  b  c
4   0  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   0  2  1
2   0  3  2
3   1  2  1
15  1  3  2
12  1  3  2
13  1  1  0
15  3  1  0
14  3  1  0
8   3  1  0
9   3  1  0
10  3  2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) if you don't care about the order in the data.

```
df['c'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].rank('dense').astype(int)
```